Find the area enclosed by the curve $(x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2y^3=0$
The curve
$$(x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2y^3=0$$
forms a heart shaped curve.

I want to find the area enclosed by it.
This curve is a sixth degree algebraic curve, so y cannot be found and x cannot be found. The implicit función theorem stays that there exist implicit funcions that solve this equation that cover some parts of the function, that is, local inverses. However, I am working with Desmos and, as far as I know, it is not posible to define a function implicitly, that is, without a explicit expression that you would type to define it.
I also tried to transform the equation to polar coordinates, but you get a fifth degree equation for r. And I havent found a way to parametrize the curve in terms of trigonometric funcions to maybe use Green's theorem to approach it.
So, is there any way to compute its area accurately? An additional problem would be to compute its perimeter.

According to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html the area is $A_1 = 3/2 \pi$.

Clearly that is not the area. You confused It with other graph. You can see from the graph that the area is clearly less than 4, and that number is greater than 4.

You are right, the area is $\approx 3.66$, which corresponds to $A_0 =3.6619...$ on that page. Which means that the indexing on that page not consistent.

$3/2\pi$ means $\dfrac3{2\pi}.$

@JohnBentin: I was referring to the list at the bottom of https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html, starting with $A_0 = 3.661972725...$, $A_1 = \frac 32 \pi$. I thought that $A_0$ is the area of the first figure (the “zeroth” curve) and $A_1$ the area of the second figure (the “first heart curve”). But apparently that is not the case.

The area is not known here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=first+heart+curve+area

You can actually isolate the $y$ in terms of $x$, no need for parametrization:
$$y^2-x^{2/3}y+x^2-1=0\iff y=\dfrac{x^{2/3}\pm\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4x^2+4}}{2}$$
Thus, the area of the heart should be
$$\mathcal A=\int_{\{-x_0|x_0^{4/3}-4x_0^2+4=0\}}^{\{x_0|x_0^{4/3}-4x_0^2+4=0\}}\int_{\frac{x^{2/3}-\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4x^2+4}}{2}}^{\frac{x^{2/3}+\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4x^2+4}}{2}}\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx\approx\int_{-1.139}^{1.139}\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4x^2+4}\,\mathrm dx\approx \boxed{3.662\text{ u}^2}$$

What does $u^2$ stand for in the result?

$u^2$ means "units squared" such as "square centimeters" or "square kilometers".

This is fine but how do you compute the integral ? Just curious. Cheers -)

I used Desmos to compute it. There's no way I would've guessed an analytic solution in terms of special functions. Even WolframAlpha yielded a horrendous expression so I opted for the numerical solution.

Just for the fun.
Starting from @Conreu good solution, if you want to generate a sequence of rational values of $x_0$ solution of
$$x_0^{4/3}-4 x_0^2+4=0$$ perform one single iteration of Newton-like method starting at $x_0=1$. This gives
$$\left\{\frac{23}{20},\frac{247}{217},\frac{2285}{2006},\frac{690275}{606023},\frac{14895029}{13076960},\frac{30132214}{26454319},\frac{1300407625}{1141681711},\frac{224485326797}{19
   7084965733}\right\}$$
The problem is that
$$\int_{-a}^{+a}\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-4 x^2+4}\,dx=2\int_0^a \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x^4}-4 x^2+4}\,dx$$ is given in terms of very long and nasty elliptic integrals (of the first, second and third kinds) with complex arguments.
